# nD "cube" from ranges

Tags: python, numpy, python-itertools

I have a mixed integer problem. I need to minimize a function, which is a weighted least square regression, the weights being dependent on the regression (iteratively reweighted least square). 7 parameters define my piecewise regression. I need to find a local minima around a first guess.

I tried to write the problem in gekko, but I somehow find it very difficult to implement. After many tries, I stopped at "negative DOF".

Anyway, I decided to brute force the problem. It works, but it's slow. I build a cube (itertools) around my working point in 7D and calculate the weighted square errors at each of the 3^7 points. I have boundaries for each dimension, and sometimes my working point is on one of the faces of my 7D domain. Technically, I have 2^p * 3^(7-p) points. I now have a list of all the values, find the minimum, move my working point there and restart building a cube, excluding all the points that I have already calculated in the previous loop steps.

Now I want to accelerate it by calculating the gradient at my working point and move faster (skip a step or two in my loop). np.gradient will require a 7d array in order to perform correctly.

Given a point, and 7 ranges around that point, how to make a 7D array in an efficient way? How to make an image of this array with the values of my function?

Please don't say 7 for loops.

Comment: For a custom function, you must either vectorize the function, or run a single loop. In either case, use `np.indices` or `np.meshgrid` to generate the arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of whether your function is vectorized, you can use an approach with [`np.indices`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html) like this:

```
base_grid = np.indices(7 * (3,), sparse=False) - 1
```

This produces an array of all the combinations of `-1, 0, 1` that you need. [`np.meshgrid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) does something similar, but the arrays will be separated into a tuple, which is inconvenient.

At each iteration, you modify the grid with your step (scale) and offset:

```
current_grid = base_grid * scale + offset
```

If your function is vectorized, you call it directly, the grid is 7 3x3x3x3x3x3x3 arrays. If it accepts seven inputs, just use star expansion.

If your function is not vectorized, you can still step along the corresponding elements in a single loop, not seven loops, using [`np.nditer`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nditer.html):

```
with np.nditer([current_grid, None],
        op_axes=[list(range(1, current_grid.ndim)), None]) as it:
    for x, y in it:
        y[:] = f(*x)
    j = it.operands[1]
```

Comment: Thanks for the tools. 
When I have current_grid, can I filter on conditions ?
Is j the image of f on current_grid?
Can I concatenate current_grid with previous loops into a map, like map=np.concatenate(map,current_grid) at each descent? Same with j into an f_map? Would it be wiser to use gradient on j or on f_map?

Comment: @HashemiEmad. That depends on how you plan to use the data. If I understand correctly, successive js are on a completely different grid